biber sourcemapping - PCRE regexp with Unicode support
I need to match an Unicode character belonging to the “uppercase letter” category with \p{Lu}.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe,
  author = {Doe, John},
  title = {Title of the ArticlĒ}, %final uppercase letter
  subtitle = {Subtitle of the Article},
  journaltitle = {Title of the Journal},
  date = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      % add \@ at the final uppercase letter (if present)
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{(\p{Lu})\Z}, replace={$1\string\\@}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{doe}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

From what I read, by default, PCRE compiles without Unicode support.
Is it possible to do something on the biber/biblatex side?

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730964/javascript-regex-for-capitalized-letters-with-accents#comment138454535_64799957:

As per regular-expressions.info/unicode.html we should add combine unicode possibilities. So, from the original question, the answer would be text.match(/(\p{Lu}\p{M}*)+/u): any uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant (\p{Lu}) followed by any number of combining marks possible (\p{M}*).

MWE (I added a Q to the replacement to make it more clear):
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe,
  author = {Doe, John},
  title = {Title of the ArticlĒ}, %final uppercase letter
  subtitle = {Subtitle of the Article},
  journaltitle = {Title of the Journal},
  date = {2023},
}
@article{smith,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  title = {Title of the ArticlO}, %final uppercase letter
  subtitle = {Subtitle of the Article},
  journaltitle = {Title of the Journal},
  date = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      % add \@ at the final uppercase letter (if present)
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{(\p{Lu}\p{M}*)\Z}, replace={$1Q\string\\@}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{doe,smith}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Result:


Thank you so much! Obviously I was unclear about key-concepts such as “single Unicode code point” and “combining mark”.
